# "Finite Rotations Are Not Vectors". Is this a good example? ("Berkeley Physics Course Mechanics Volume 1 Second Edition" by Charles Kittel et al..)

Tags: vectors, examples-counterexamples

I am reading "Berkeley Physics Course Mechanics Volume 1 Second Edition" by Charles Kittel et al..

> To be a vector a quantity must satisfy two conditions:
>
> 1. It must satisfy the parallelogram law of addition.
> 2. It must have a magnitude and a direction independent of the choice of coordinate system.
>
> *Finite Rotations Are Not Vectors*
> Not all quantities that have magnitude and direction are necessarily vectors. For example, a rotation of a rigid body about a particular axis fixed in space has a magnitude (the angle of rotation) and a direction (the direction of the axis). But two such rotations do not combine according to the vector law of addition, unless the angles of rotation are infinitesimally small. This is easily seen when the two axes are perpendicular to each other and the rotations are by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rad $(90^\circ)$. Consider the object (a book) in Fig. 2.8a. The rotation (1) leaves it as in Fig. 2.8b, and a subsequent rotation (2) about another axis leaves the object as in Fig. 2.8c. But if to the object as originally oriented (Fig. 2.8d) we apply first the rotation (2), (Fig. 2.8e) and then the rotation (1), the object ends up as shown in Fig. 2.8f. The orientation in the sixth figure is *not* the same as in the third. Obviously the commutative law of addition is not satisfied by these rotations. Despite the fact that they have a magnitude and a direction, finite rotations cannot be represented as vectors.

[image]

The authors showed finite rotations are not vectors because finite rotations don't satisfy the axioms of a vector space. (the commutative law.)
This book is a very famous book, but I doubt this example is a good example.

For example,

> Suppose $v_1,v_2$ are Euclidean vectors.
> We define $v_1+v_2:=v_1-v_2$. ("$-$" is the usual subtraction operator.)
> Then, obviously this addition doesn't satisfy the axioms of a vector space.

We can easily make examples like this in which the sum of vectors doesn't satisfy the axioms of a vector space.

Is the example in the book a good example?

Comment: Its the other way around,  Rotations in euclidan $R^n$  are specified by a 2-d plane and an angle or more generally by an even number of reflections (Artin).  So its a map in $R^n$ that in high school trigonometry  is shortened to it dual,  an orientation dependent, "axial vector". Kittel wtites in 1950, when physicists just began to learn about representations of groups. If one tries to learn from such outdated books, the odds  are low to reach the current level of theoretical physics  at all, or at least in an acceptable time.

Comment: @RolandF Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @RolandF My goal is just to understand mechanics and electromagnetism. But this goal is hard to me.

Comment: There are three classical texts, I appreciate for this goal, Goldsteins Classical mechanics, Wheelers Chapter II about Forms and Electromagnetism in "Gravitation" and Kittels short introduction to Quantum theory in his "Quantum Theory of Solids".  Modernized and bound  together, but hard to study without advisor is Frankels "Geometry of Physics"

Comment: @RolandF Thank you very much for your recommendation.